# Get x posts from x categories -Wordpress REST API v2

Tags: jquery, wordpress-rest-api

I'm working on a JQuery hybrid app for a Wordpress based news site.  The site has a landing page which shows x amount of posts from x categories which they deem to be trending.  I have access to the list of catgeories which they change regularly.

Is there some way of using the Wordpress REST API v2 to pull x amount of posts from those x category ids?  I would love a client side solution as the news site is wary about making server side php changes, but if I have to go down that route I can.

What I have at the moment is x amount of ajax calls which doesn't seem like a nice solution at all.

Thanks